# GWT cannot parse timezones like BST ans EDT

Tags: java, gwt

I'm kinda new to GWT.

I have been trying to parse a date in the format "`dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm z`" but I get an exception when the timezone is EDT or BST.

Doesn't GWT support these timezones while parsing? If so, is there any alternative way which I can use to parse the date using EDT?

Please help.

Code snippet:

```
DateTimeFormat dateParser = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm z");
String fomattedDate = dateParser.format(date,Timezone.createTimeZone(TimeZoneConstants.americaNewYork));
Date newDate = dateTimeParser.parse(formattedDate);
```

This line gives me exception.

After reading the docs for `DateTimeFormat` it said that it supports a lower number of timezones while parsing.

Comment: Can you share the code you are using? Have you checked if the calls you are making are passing these timezones to the browser, and that it is JS (and not the GWT framework) which is failing to parse them?

Comment: Hi Colin I have attached the code snippet. Please have a look and share your inputs.

Comment: It works if you change the format to `dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm Z` - capital `Z` as time zone.

Comment: I tried but still givese an illegalArgumentException. I have tried with z, Z, v but it still cant parse the timezone

Comment: Maybe comment is not enough. I've posted my code in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works for me:

```
TimeZoneConstants timeZoneConstants = GWT.create(TimeZoneConstants.class);
DateTimeFormat dateParser = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm Z");
String formattedDate = dateParser.format(date, TimeZone.createTimeZone(timeZoneConstants.americaNewYork()));
Date newDate = dateParser.parse(formattedDate);
```

I have created `TimeZoneConstants` via deferred binding and changed the format to `dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm Z` (capital `Z`) - with `z` I did got an `IllegalArgumentException` indeed.

If you still get issues, try inspect deeply the parsing function to track down the exact problem.

Comment: Thanks Adam. Just one more question here, when I put the value after parsing in a java.util.Date object it agains converts my formatted date to GMT timezone. How can I keep it in EDT timezone and put in  a date object ? Actually I need to set values in this object once its parsed.

Comment: I'm afraid it's hardly possible in GWT since java.util.Date has always the browser's timezone. Check [Client side time zone support in GWT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686448/client-side-time-zone-support-in-gwt) question for example or ask another question. I'm glad I could help with parsing.