# Google GWT or ICEFaces to develop a rich internet application?

Tags: gwt, icefaces

I would like to develop a rich internet application but i can´t decide for a technology.

Have someone an idea where are the better benefits between this two frameworks?

Google GWT (Google) or ICEFaces (http://www.icesoft.org/java/projects/ICEfaces/overview.jsf).

Thanks for your Answers.

Greetings, Javacode

Answer (score 0):

You should know exactly pros and cons of each framework . And you should think about various view of your project for future. Maintainance , performance , code-reuseable and so on..

Here Pros and cons of GWT -http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/01/gwt-pros-and-cons.html

And here concern with detail info of GWT.
[Biggest GWT Pitfalls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99866/biggest-gwt-pitfalls)
[Why GWT? Advantages and Trade-Offs of Using This RIA Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097964/why-gwt-advantages-and-trade-offs-of-using-this-ria-framework)
You asked concern with two framework. There concern with many frameworks..
[Pros and Cons of Various Java Web Presentation Layer Technologies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538550/pros-and-cons-of-various-java-web-presentation-layer-technologies)
May be helpful for you...