# How to do calendar operations in Java GWT? How to add days to a Date?

Tags: java, gwt

Since GWT does not provide the GregorianCalendar class, how to do calendar operations on the client?

I have a Date `a` and I want the Date, which is `n` days after `a`.

Examples:

```
a (2000-01-01) + n (1) -> 2000-01-02
a (2000-01-01) + n (31) -> 2000-02-01
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Updated answer for GWT 2.1

```
final Date dueDate = new Date();
CalendarUtil.addDaysToDate(dueDate, 21);
```

Edit: the fully qualified name of this class is [com.google.gwt.user.datepicker.client.CalendarUtil](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/datepicker/client/CalendarUtil.html).

Comment: The alternative answer by @Chris Lercher can help if you need to add a unit of time besides Days (i.e: hours)

Answer (score 10):

The answer that Google seems to use (currently), is:

```
  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") // GWT requires Date
  public static void addDaysToDate(Date date, int days) {
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
  }
```

This is from the class `com.google.gwt.user.datepicker.client.CalendarUtil`, which is used by `com.google.gwt.user.datepicker.client.DatePicker`. I imagine, that there will be problems involved, when doing calculations in different timezones.

Lots of people have already voted for some kind of Joda time for GWT: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=603 . The currently last comment states, that there's a new fork of goda time, maybe we should really check it out.

Comment: You can similarly call Date's other set methods for adding different units of time (i.e: setHours)

Answer (score 3):

```
private static final long MILLISECONDS_IN_SECOND = 1000l;
private static final long SECONDS_IN_MINUTE = 60l;
private static final long MINUTES_IN_HOUR = 60l;
private static final long HOURS_IN_DAY = 24l;
private static final long MILLISECONDS_IN_DAY = MILLISECONDS_IN_SECOND *
        SECONDS_IN_MINUTE *
        MINUTES_IN_HOUR *
        HOURS_IN_DAY;
public Date addDays (Date date, days)
{
 return new Date (date.getTime () + (days * MILLISECONDS_IN_DAY));
}
```

this will work with leap years but will *eventually* stray by milliseconds on milleniums when we add or drop leap seconds.

Comment: +1, but please note: It depends very much on what you want to achieve. Usually, adding 7 days to "2011-03-22 10:00:00 CET" should result in "2011-03-29 10:00:00 CET" (i.e. the local time should stay at 10 o'clock). But because in CET, a clock change (DST) occurs between the two dates, the millisecond calculation will yield a different result. Again, it depends on what kind of calculation you want!

Comment: This fails for daylight saving. Over a daylight savings night, adding 24 hours is not the same as adding 1 day.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a rough implementation that emulates TimeZone, Calendar, and Locale.  Feel free to try it out here:

http://code.google.com/p/gwt-calendar-class/downloads/list