# how to add months to the date without Calendar?

Tags: java, gwt, date

I'm now developing gwt project that want to add month to the given date. gwt doesn't support Calendar class so how can I do this ? Date is in `"dd.MM.yyyy"` format

```
public Date addMonth(Date d, int months){
}
```

mine implementation is so long that I need help. Thanks

**[EDIT]**

addMonth() means just add months to the given date's month. If it is `01.06.2010` adding 4 months is `01.10.2010`

for 31 Jan and add 1 it will 28. Feb

Comment: what does it mean to add a month?  what is january 31st plus one month?  is it february 28th?  is it march 1st?

Comment: I'm now editing. sorry for misconception

Comment: It's still unclear what Jan 31st plus one month is

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can use CalendarUtil

```
import com.google.gwt.user.datepicker.client.CalendarUtil;
...
// Now
Date d = new Date();
// Now + 2 months
CalendarUtil.addMonthsToDate(d, 2);
```

Answer (score 3):

Take look at [How to do calendar operations in Java GWT? How to add days to a Date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527845/how-to-do-calendar-operations-in-java-gwt-how-to-add-days-to-a-date)

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Ofcourse you will have to refine this based on how many days in a month and stuff but you get the basic idea. I am not familiar with gwt but I assumed it doesn't support joda time.

This is a rather crude solution. But without using the Calendar class or joda-time this is the only way I can think of for now.

```
        Date date = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy"); //today is 02.02.2011
        Date baseDate = null;
        try {
            baseDate = df.parse(df.format(date));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        long oneMonthTime = baseDate.getTime()+30*24*60*60; //30 should change based on which month you are on
        System.out.println(df.format(oneMonthTime)); //prints 03.02.2011
```