# How to get a java.util.Date which is a year back than the current date without using SimpleDateFormat or Calendar

Tags: java, date

I have the current date and I want to get the date which is 1 year back by using only `java.util.Date`

I'm working in gwt so cannot use `SimpleDateFormat` or `Calendar`

```
Date currentDate = new Date();
Date oneYearBefore = new Date( - (365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
```

The above mentioned code is not working (got it from some forum)

Comment: That expression will overflow the int datatype. Try using long constants. (e.g. 365L * 24L *60L...). Also you have not taken daylight saving or leap seconds into account. Do they matter for your use cases?

Comment: This will cause you a lot of pain because you also have to check for leap years and the like.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do calendar operations in Java GWT? How to add days to a Date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527845/how-to-do-calendar-operations-in-java-gwt-how-to-add-days-to-a-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using all `int's`, when you multiply them you get an int. You're converting that int to a long, but only after the int multiplication has already resulted in the wrong answer.
Actually it is `overflowing the int type`

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date currentDate = new Date();
        System.out.println(currentDate);
        long milliseconds = (long) 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
        Date oneYearBefore = new Date(currentDate.getTime() - milliseconds);
        System.out.println(oneYearBefore);
    }

Mon Nov 17 13:11:10 IST 2014
Sun Nov 17 13:11:10 IST 2013
```

Comment: There is a bug here, it should be : long milliseconds = (long) 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
        Date oneYearBefore = new Date(currentDate.getTime() - milliseconds);

Answer (score 4):

Use Calendar class

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);
System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

Why You cannot use Calendar? I think You might have misunderstood something?

anyways:

```
Date oneYearBefore = new Date( System.currentTimeMillis() - (365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
```

Or by using Your code pasted from the forum:

```
Date currentDate = new Date();
Date oneYearBefore = new Date( currentDate.getTime() - (365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
```

Comment: A year is not always exactly 365 times 24 hours.

Comment: http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20090707173543/wykopedia/pl/images/9/9b/200px-CaptainobviousChooseOption.jpg

Do You prefer to give us a nice implementation of Gregorian Calendar? In most applications this is sufficient.

Comment: I guess in gwt I'm not allowed to use Calendar. It says no source code found for java.util.Calendar in runtime.

Comment: How about this Util, maybe it will be usefull (then its just -365 days)? 
http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/datepicker/client/CalendarUtil.html

Answer (score 0):

Using only `java.util.Date`, you can use:

```
Date oneYearBefore = new Date(currentDate.getTime() - (365L * 24L * 60L * 60L * 1000L));
```

But keep in mind, this doesn't account for potential leap years.