# GWT Date equivalent to java.util.Calendar

Tags: java, gwt, calendar

I want to get the date of a particular day of the week e.g Wednessday. i.e If today's date is 27th Friday, Wednessday would infact be the  25th .

I could achieve this by

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.WEDNESDAY);
String thisWed = String.format("%tF%n", calendar)
```

The challenge here is that `java.util.Calendar` is not supported in GWT client side, Is there a possible solution without having to move this code to server side ?

Thanks

Comment: Duplicates earlier http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009655/how-to-use-java-util-calendar-in-gwt

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`com.google.gwt.user.datepicker.client.CalendarUtil`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/datepicker/client/CalendarUtil.html) is what you are looking for, I guess;

Answer (score 2):

Easiest would probably be to use Joda-time or similar, but all GWT ports of JodaTime have been abandonned: [Date time library for gwt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311754/date-time-library-for-gwt)

The most performant (no third-party dependency) would be to do the calculation yourself:

```
Date d = new Date();
int dow = d.getDay();
int wed_delta = 3 - dow;
wed = new Date(d.getTime() + (86400 * wed_delta));
```

(the last line could be replaced with `CalendarUtil.addDaysToDate(d, wed_delta)`, modifying `d` in-place)

Comment: Hi thomas, First glance at your logic, It looks OK but when I ran it, I get `Fri Apr 27 18:25:48 CAT 2012` . With my code above, I would get `Last Wednessday: 2012-04-25`. I expect to get the last Wednesday of that week of new Date().

Answer (score 1):

using `DateTimeFormat`, it allows format a java.util.Date into string or format a string into Date.

```
Date date = new Date();
DateTimeFormat format = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("EEEE");
String day = format.parse(date);
```

Comment: Thanks but doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Calendar emulation and org.jresearch.commons.gwt.shared.tools.Dates utility class from open/gwt project on bitbucket (https://bitbucket.org/JRS/open-gwt)

The emulation and utility class based on ftr-gwt-library project (https://code.google.com/p/ftr-gwt-library/)