# How to replace getDate() from the type Date which is deprecated?

Tags: java, date, calendar, getdate

I have an existing program that I have to correct . It contains these lines :

```
        Date startDate = new Date();
        int day = startDate.getDate() - 1;
```

but **getDate()** from the type **Date** is deprecated so i have to change it using **Calender**. I tried this :

```
Calendar startDate = Calendar.getInstance();
startDate.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
int day= startDate.getTime();
```

but this results into following error :

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Date to int

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to get day in month use this:

```
int day= startDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

If you want to get day in week use this:

```
int day= startDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

Also be careful about day of week, because day 0 is sunday not monday.

> Field number for get and set indicating the day of the week. This
>   field takes values SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY,
>   FRIDAY, and SATURDAY.

Comment: seems like Calender class is not supported from GWT. I got this error while compiling : " No source code is available for type java.util.Calendar; did you forget to inherit a required module?"

Comment: I didn't notice that you use GWT. I am not familiar with GWT but check this response: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009655/how-to-use-java-util-calendar-in-gwt

Answer (score 6):

One more good option is to use like :

```
System.out.println(DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date()));
```

It will print the current date.

If you need time along with date then you can use like :

```
System.out.println(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()));
```

Answer (score 0):

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Date to int

change

```
  int day= startDate.getTime();
```

to

```
 Date dat= startDate.getTime();//return type Date
```

Answer (score 0):

As the javadocs suggest, use Calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

Answer (score 0):

To get the day of the month:

```
int day= startDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

From the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_MONTH):

> Field number for get and set indicating the day of the month. This is
>   a synonym for DATE. The first day of the month has value 1.

Answer (score 0):

The *getTime()* function will return a Date Object which cannot be converted to int. If you want to get the day as an integer, you have to use:

```
int day = startDate.get(Calendar.DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

See on java doc at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime():

`Date` object of `getTime()` method return `long` not in `int` so use like:

```
long time = startDate.getTime();
```

For `Calendar` docs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime()
Use like below:

```
long time = startDate.getTime().getTime();
```

For day of month:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int dayOfMonth = c.get(Calendar.DATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Date#startDate.getDate() returns the day of the month :

- Code#1-->

  ```
  Date startDate = new Date();
  int day = startDate.getDate() - 1;
  System.out.println(day);
  ```

Through Calendar#.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) you will get the same result as Date#startDate.getDate():

- Code#2-->

  ```
  Calendar startDate = Calendar.getInstance();
  int day= startDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)-1;
  System.out.println(day);
  ```

So you can replace Code#1 by Code#2

Comment: seems like Calender class is not supported from GWT .

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

The old java.util.Date/.Calendar classes are notoriously troublesome. They have been supplanted in Java 8 and later by the new java.time framework.

Note the use of time zone. Crucial in determining a date. If omitted, you implicitly rely on the JVM’s current default time zone. Better to specify the desired/expected time zone.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( zoneId );
int dayOfMonth = now.getDayOfMonth();
int dayOfWeek = now.getDayOfWeek().getValue();
int dayOfYear = now.getDayOfYear();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply type int day = startDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);