# How to replace setDate and getDate

Tags: java, deprecated

Deprecated code, how to replace `setDate` and `getDate`, right now code works, but I can’t present it like that. I have tried Calendar, and I don’t see how that works. Code point is to move exact amount of days back in my calendar.

```
public void minusDay() {
    int days = dateRange();
    toDate.setDate(toDate.getDate()-days);
```

Comment: "Right now code works". Then don't touch it.

Comment: Do you talk about `java.util.Date`?

Comment: Yes, it is java.util.Date.

Comment: *assuming* it is `java.util.Date`(there are more than 10 `setDate()` methods in Java SE), the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html#setDate(int)) says: "**Deprecated.**
As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by Calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, int date)." (most deprecated methods/fields have a message with an alternative)

Comment: You either don't touch your working code or you switch it entirely to using `java.time` instead of `java.util`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace getDate() from the type Date which is deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32694110/how-to-replace-getdate-from-the-type-date-which-is-deprecated)

Comment: `setTime`? [deHaar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58536328/how-to-replace-setdate-and-getdate#comment103395477_58536328) means the [`java.base/java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) package - "The main API for **dates**, times, instants, and durations." - and its classes (the not-so-new API to be used instead of `Date`, `Calendar`, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 Date API supports `minusDays` and `plusDays` methods on `LocalDateTime` instances.

If you don't want to convert your whole system using the Java 8 Date API, then you can just convert your `Date` object into `LocalDateTime` and work on it. You will also need to use `ZonedDateTime` to take into consideration the timezone also for the conversion.

```
public void minusDay() {
    int days = dateRange();
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(toDate.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
    ldt.minusDays(days);
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    toDate = Date.from(zdt.toInstant());
}
```

Source [here](https://www.java67.com/2016/03/how-to-convert-date-to-localdatetime-in-java8-example.html).